# How to add border color on mat button , right border / left border?

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to add right border color to a mat-stroked button , but i am unable to achieve the results .

```
<button class="example" mat-stroked-button>New <br /> Comment</button>
```

CSS-

```
    .example{
  color: red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-right: black;
}
```

But that doesnt work , replacing border-right with border gives the border throughout which i dont want , i want border color only at the right border .

Can anyone help me achieve this ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzhuny?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css is this what you want or not?

Comment: Absolutely yes , border-right-color , man that didnt come up in my intelli-sense ever . Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo in this [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzhuny?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

You need `border-right-color: black;`...

Your css class `.example` is as below..

```
.example {
  color: red;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-right-color: black;
}
```